# Problems changing variable in #if

Tags: c, if-statement, c-preprocessor

I have some problems in understanding how the `#if` preprocessor directive works.

From this code:

```
int a, b;

#define VAR (a | b) 

void foo(int x)
{
    if(x)
        a = smth;
        b = smth2;
    else
        a = xmth;
        b = xmth2;
}   
int main()
{
    foo(x);
    #if(VAR != 0)
    {
        f = VAR;
    }
}
```

I can only change `foo()`, but whatever the values for `xmth/smth` I get `f=0`. Why?

Comment: I have seen some dupes, but can't find them right now. `#if` is a **preprocessor** directive, it's executed **before** compilation and does no longer exist in the final program. You get `f==0` because `VAR` is nothing, the preprocessor doesn't even know `a` or `b`.

Comment: Uh, you're kidding with those unbraced `if/else` lines in `foo()`, right?

Comment: It's just a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preprocessor directives are interpreted before compiling your program.** So `VAR` has no knowledge of `a` and `b`. See [C preprocessor on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).

---

Instead, you could create a macro that takes parameters, like this:

```
#define VAR(a,b) (a | b)
```

...and use it like that:

```
#if (VAR(a,b) != 0)
```

You would have to adapt your program, since `a` and `b` don't belong to the scope of your `main()` function.

Comment: Can I go something like: `#define VAR(a,b) (a | b) ` then `#define BIGVAR VAR`  And `#if (BIGVAR !=0)`?

Comment: @user3623498 No you can't. Don't try to find a hack like this, it won't work. You will need to pass parameters to your macro at some point.

Comment: But `#if....` is still a preprocessor directive and foo() won't be able to change anything relevant for this `#if`